# Find rows common in more than two files using awk

Tags: linux, awk

I have tab delimited text files in which common rows between them are to be found based on columns 1 and 2 as key columns.
Sample files:

```
file1.txt 

aba 0 0 
abc 0 1
abd 1 1 
xxx 0 0

file2.txt

xyz 0 0
aba 0 0 0 0
xxx 0 0
abc 1 1

file3.txt

xyx 0 0
aba 0 0 
aba 0 1 0
xxx 0 0 0 1
abc 1 1
```

I would like to get rows common in 2 files or 3 files using columns 1 and 2 as key to search. For the common rows based on column 1 and 2 reporting the first occurrence in any file would do the job.

Sample Output for rows common in 2 files:

```
abc 1 1
```

Sample output for rows common in 3 files:

```
 aba 0 0
 xxx 0 0
```

In real scenario I do have to specify different values for number of files. Can anybody suggest a generalized solution to pass the value for number of files in which it has to be common.

I have this piece of code which looks for rows common in all files.

```
awk '
FNR == NR { 
    arr[$1,$2] = 1
    line[$1,$2] = line[$1,$2] ( line[$1,$2] ? SUBSEP : "" ) $0
    next
}
FNR == 1 { delete found }
{ if ( arr[$1,$2] && ! found[$1,$2] ) { arr[$1,$2]++; found[$1,$2] = 1 } }
END { 
    num_files = ARGC -1 
    for ( key in arr ) {
        if ( arr[key] < num_files ) { continue }
        split( line[ key ], line_arr, SUBSEP )
        for ( i = 1; i <= length( line_arr ); i++ ) { 
            printf "%s\n", line_arr[ i ]
        } 
    } 
}
' *.txt  > commoninall.txt
```

Comment: did u used -v ?  awk -v NumberFiles ???  this will allow you to use the variable inside awk  Do you have a piece of code?http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/34977-passing-argument-into-awk.html

Comment: oh wait. after a second read to your question, i found myself cannot understand what you are asking.

Comment: I think the OP really needs the number of files as a dynamic input (-v) to make awk compare more files . I think his awk is now working to compare the files, but not to load N files (I mean file1.txt, file2.txt, .... fileN.txt)

Comment: too ambiguous. i can't understand

Comment: How about: `cat file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt | sort | awk ...` ?

Comment: @Peter Paul Kiefer's can be modified nicely: `cat file[123].txt | sort | uniq -c | grep '^ *3'`, but this only works if you can guarantee that no line appears twice in any of the input files.

Comment: But this question really makes no sense.  As asked, it is not at all clear why the first two columns are to be treated differently than the others.

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz  I have posted the code in OP which looks for common rows in all the files based on key columns 1 and 2 and reports the first occurrence in any file.

Comment: @WilliamPursell the first two columns are used as a key to search

Comment: I think what @PeterPaulKiefer is a usefull way to do the same... does it work for you? you just need to accumulate the number of ocurrences and print where num > 1..

Comment: in the code does `a[i]>1` means that number of occurences in more than one file? If yes, could it be written as `a[i]==3` to get only the occurences in 3 files and so on by varying the number.

Comment: i agree with you. i posted it by modifying as i couldn't find a solution in the previous post

Comment: As a general rule, rather than asking a new question, you should revise your old question to clarify issues raised in comments.  Doing so gives it another chance at the front page.  I've updated my answer to the duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
cat file[123].txt | sort | awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"; V1=""; V2=""} 
    {if (V1==$1 && V2==$2) { b=b+1 } else 
    { print b":"$0; b=1; V1=$1; V2=$2} }' |grep "2:"|awk '
    BEGIN{FS=":"} {print $2}'
```

I cat all file in one stream, sort the lines, check if the first two tab seperated colums are equal (if they are then print the line) and then filter out all duplicated lines.

BTW: I took this nice file[123].txt globbing idea from the comment of William Pursell.

Comment: this solution works slighty different from required output. The solution outputs only the lines that appears twice in some of the input files.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question (a bit ;-) ). I added an improved version! This is the 2 file version. Change the 2: after the grep to 3: and you have the 3 file version.

Comment: Ah no. Ii will work only if there is at most one line of each key in one of the files. I have how to achieve that but tonight I'm too tired. I will look at it tomorrow.

Comment: im about to comment the same. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should work too

I put all the lines in an array (b) with two first values and accumulate in a the number of repetitions. If number > 1 it will be printed from b which has the last line saved for this pair combination column1/column2

`cat *.txt | awk -F" " '{a[$1$2]=a[$1$2]+1; b[$1$2]=$0} END{ for (i in a){if(a[i]>1){print b[i]}}}'`

Is it ok too?

**EDIT**

To show all lines in all files, you need just a little more:

`cat *.txt | awk -F" " '{a[$1$2]=a[$1$2]+1; c=a[$1$2]; b[$1$2c]=$0} END{ for (i in a){if(a[i]>1){for(c=1; c<=a[i];++c){print b[i c]}}}}'`

Very thanks to  @PeterPaulKiefer for the cat *txt idea

Comment: NOTE: I used -F " " as the copy paste was without tabs, just remove to use tabs

Comment: It works nearly as expected. However, in the real data there seems to be  some lines that appears twice in some of the input files which is pointed out by Peter paul Kiefer.

Comment: I added a new edit !! try now plz !

Comment: i confused you. the initial solution seems to work. in the code `a[i]>1` gives which are common in more than 1 and `a[i] >2` gives which are common in more than 2. But could you let me know if there is a way to output rows which are common only in 2 or which are common only in 3 ...

Comment: do you mean a[i]==3 ? or 3 different files??

Comment: do you mean controlling exactly the cause "the line appears in three files, but not three times necessarily?"  it could be 2times in fileA, 1 in fileB, 1in file C but should be shown?

Comment: if we use 3 then it should be present in all 3 files, 1 time each in fileA, fileB and fileC.  As u said 2 times in fileA, in such cases it should also be present two times in all the three files. NOTE: When we say 2times in fileA it means that only key columns1and2 are present 2times and the rest of the columns differ.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78748/discussion-between-chas-and-alejandro-teixeira-munoz).